# kivy qpython script to apk

Tags: kivy, qpython

I am developing android app using qpython and kivy. When i execute the script in qpython in android device it is executing perfectly. My question is how can i convert the script to standalone apk?

script is as follow:

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-

#qpy:2

#qpy:kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


class LoginScreen(GridLayout):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LoginScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 2

        self.add_widget(Label(text="Username:"))
        self.username = TextInput(multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)

        self.add_widget(Label(text="Password:"))
        self.password = TextInput(multiline=False, password=True)
        self.add_widget(self.password)


class SimpleKivy(App):

    def build(self):
        return LoginScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    SimpleKivy().run()
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow the instructions in the [Kivy documentation](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-android.html#packaging-android).

Comment: thank you, got it. do you have any idea on how to launch another application from kivy app.

Comment: You could use pyjnius to dispatch an appropriate intent.